# How can I make `setf` work with `plist-get`?

Tags: setf, plists

There's no built-in setter for `plist-get`. Example:

```
(let ((pl '(:what (one))))
  (push 'two (plist-get pl :what))
  pl)
```

Error: `let*: Symbol’s function definition is void: \(setf\ plist-get\)`

How can I make `setf` work with `plist-get`?

Comment: Good question, and good answer @wasamasa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trivial to define your own:

```
(gv-define-simple-setter plist-get plist-put)

(let ((pl '(:what (one))))
  (push 'two (plist-get pl :what))
  pl) ; => (:what (two one))
```

You can find more examples in gv.el.